# preg_match function doesn't work with parenthesis

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to match an array that contains:

```
[title] => Something (12) Pieces
```

with an `$item` string that contains also `Something (12) Pieces` with this function:

```
function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'. $item .'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
```

But it doesn't give me a match even though they're identical. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Transforming an array to json, to check if a key has some value, seems a totally crazy idea! Why you don't use a simple loop?

Comment: And why do you need to use `preg_match` since you are looking for a literal string and not a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is escape characters which are special for RegEx. To achieve this you can use the function `preg_quote`, but be aware that delimiters don't get escaped by `preg_quote`, if you don't pass the used delimiter (in your case `/`) to the second argument.

```
function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'. preg_quote($item, '/') .'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
```

http://php.net/preg_quote
https://3v4l.org/p9n43

Comment: Ah, I knew something was wrong there! Spank you very much :) Will accept your answer in 9 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong, you want transform an array to JSON only to check if a value exists in the array. That's a waste of resources, in particular if the array is big.

An other way (that seems more logical in my opinion) consists to use a recursive function that loops through the array:

```
function in_array_r($value, &$array) {
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (is_array($v) && in_array_r($value, $v) || $v === $value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$myarray = [ 1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, ['title' => 'Something (12) Pieces'], 7, 8]];

var_dump(in_array_r('Something (12) Pieces', $myarray));
```